# SQL select query taking long time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the below SQL query  but it takes more than 180 sec to execute. Is there a way to speed it up ? This SQL give me the pic_id and of all the females.

```
SELECT pic_id, small
FROM picture
WHERE hide =0
AND userhide =0
AND  `fbid` 
IN (

      SELECT fbid
      FROM user
      WHERE gender =  "female"
   )

ORDER BY  `picture`.`pic_id` ASC 
LIMIT 1500 , 200
```

The Explain SQL

```
id select_type         table    type   possible_keys  key      key_len  ref   rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY             picture  index  NULL           PRIMARY  4        NULL  1700  Using where
2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  user     ALL    NULL           NULL     NULL     NULL  7496  Using where
```

--- Result of explain statement for Tim's sql answer --

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  picture ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    41443   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  user    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7501    Using where; Using join buffer
```

-- Structure ---

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`sid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`birthday` date NOT NULL,
`location` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`created` date NOT NULL,
`fbid` bigint(50) NOT NULL,
`token` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`relationship_status` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`smallest` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`ref` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
KEY `gender` (`gender`),
KEY `fbid` (`fbid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7595 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

---- structure of picture table ---

```
CREATE TABLE `picture` (
 `fbid` bigint(50) NOT NULL,
 `pic_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pic_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `hide` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `small` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `userhide` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `likes` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `hot` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pic_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `pic_location` (`pic_location`),
 UNIQUE KEY `small` (`small`),
 KEY `fbid` (`fbid`),
 KEY `hide` (`hide`),
 KEY `userhide` (`userhide`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=42749 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` to the front of the query and post the results

Comment: table create DDL would be nice too.

Comment: @AdrianCornish  - I update the Explain's result

Comment: @TimG - How to do that , I am not good in SQL ?

Comment: @AdiMathur Tim is basically asking for the CREATE statements of the tables so the structure can be seen with the indexes

Comment: Quick look at the explain (not sure because of formating alignment) but basically you are getting 1700 rows * 7496 rows - which seems a lot

Comment: @AdrianCornish - Could you please tell me the SQL statement for that ?

Comment: @AdiMathur http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: your auto inc col should be unsigned - just sayin.  :)

Comment: @TimG - you mean the ``pic_id`` or `sid` which is currently `int(11)` should be unsigned ? :)

Comment: auto incrementing fields will never be < 0 due to the nature of auto increment. you're accidentally restricting the maximum value that field can hold by half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SELECT pic_id, small
FROM picture
INNER JOIN user ON ( picture.fbid = user.fbid and user.gender='female' )
WHERE hide =0
AND userhide =0
ORDER BY  `picture`.`pic_id` ASC 
LIMIT 1500 , 200
```

I put gender in the join because a query will not return rows that don't have a match on an inner join.

You should also read [this stack overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery)

EDIT:

make sure you have indexed the following fields:

```
picture.fbid
user.fbid
user.gender
picture.hide
picture.userhide
```

Comment: Thanks , It is now 5 seconds. Is this fine or should it be more faster ?

Comment: post another explain for this query. :)  5 seconds seems slow to me still.

Comment: Please have a look . I updated the Question with the `CREATE TABLE `picture` ` values

Comment: I think the Indexing was also a problem , Its giving now `( 200 total, Query took 0.0138 sec) ` :)

I hope the structure that I posted up is correct :) 

PS: Accepting Answer , Thank you :)

Comment: .138 seconds sounds more like it. :) glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Try using a join instead:

```
SELECT p.pic_id, p.small
FROM picture p
INNER JOIN fbid f USING ( fbid )
WHERE p.hide =0
AND p.userhide =0
AND f.gender = 'female'
ORDER BY  `picture`.`pic_id` ASC 
LIMIT 1500 , 200
```